# Not able download pdf from url with out extension using download manager -Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to download the pdf  from a url  with out pdf extension using download manager  and  am gettig the status 16(download failed)
[https://xxxxxxxx.net/order/print/ticket?id=xxxxj6qyw9o](https://platinumlist.net/order/print/ticket?id=425j6qyw9o) -download failed -Also am not show the url in web view
https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf  -working fine

```
val request = DownloadManager
           .Request(Uri.parse("https://xxxxx.net/order/print/ticket?id=xxxj6qyw9o"))
           .setMimeType("application/pdf")
           .setTitle("test.pdf")
           .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
               Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
               "$fileName"
           )


           .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
      .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
       val dm: DownloadManager =
           context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
       val downloadId = dm.enqueue(request)

val downloadBroadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
           override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
               var id: Long? = intent?.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
               if (id == downloadId) {
                   val cursor: Cursor =
                       dm.query(DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId))
                   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                       val status =
                           cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))
                       if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                           Toast.makeText(
                               context,
                               context.resources.getString(R.string.ticket_download_success),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                           ).show()
                           context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                       } else {
                           Toast.makeText(
                               context,
                               context.resources.getString(R.string.ticket_download_fail),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                           ).show()
                           context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```